# How can I map Alt+` to Alt+Shift+Tab in Windows with AutoHotKey?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

In Mac, it is possible to use Alt+` (aka backquote, backtick) instead of Alt+Shift+Tab to cycle through open apps.

I tried creating the same mapping using AutoHotKey but failed.

The closest I came to making this work is this

```
Alt & `::ShiftAltTab
```

But now when I press Alt+` then Alt+Tab without releasing the Alt key, Alt+Tab cycles backwards as if it were Shift+Alt+Tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-add the normal behaviour of <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> will fix it:

```
Alt & `::ShiftAltTab
Alt & Tab::AltTab
```